# Japanese Temple Problem From 1844

Tags: geometry, sangaku

I recently learnt a Japanese geometry temple problem.

The problem is the following:

**Five squares are arranged as the image shows. Prove that the area of triangle *T* and the area of  square *S* are equal.**

[image]

This is problem 6 in this [article.](https://sms.math.nus.edu.sg/smsmedley/Vol-24-2/Traditional%20Japanese%20Geometry%20(John%20F%20Rigby).pdf)
I am thinking about law of cosines, but I have not been able to prove the theorem. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: If you like this kind of problems I cannot recommend enough the book "Sacred Mathematics - Japanese Temple Geometry" by Fukagawa Hidetoshi and Tony Rothman. It also includes a couple of "relatives" to this problem.

Comment: I checked it out. A great book indeed, thank you.

Comment: The shapes $S,T$ share a vertex $A$ where $6$ angles meet, $3$ of them right angles. Thus the other $3$ angles sum to $\pi/2$. Let $\theta$ be the angle in $T$, so the two other acute angles and the right angle between them from $S$ sum to $\pi-\theta$. As $\sin\theta=\sin(\pi-\theta)$, $T$ has the same area as $\triangle ABC$ where $BA,AC$ are sides of the upper squares.

The challenge then is to show $S$ has that much area too. Let $D$ denote the vertex of $S$ opposite $A$. I suspect we can show the quadrilateral $BACD$ has twice the area of $S$, and also twice the area of $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: ^ From J.G.'s answer.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

We will, first of all, prove a very interesting property

> $\mathbf{Lemma\;1}$
>
> Given two squares PQRS and PTUV (as shown on the picture), the triangles $\Delta STP$ and $\Delta PVQ$ have equal area.

$\mathbf {Proof}$

[image]

Denote by $\alpha$ the angle SPT and by $[...]$ the area of the polygon "...". Hence
$$[\Delta STP]=\frac{\overline {PS}\cdot\overline {PT}\cdot \sin(\alpha)}{2}$$ $$[\Delta PVQ]=\frac{\overline {QP}*\overline {PV}\cdot\sin\Bigl(360°-(90°+90+\alpha)\Bigr)}{2}=\frac{\overline {QP}\cdot\overline {PV}\cdot\sin\Bigl(180°-\alpha\Bigr)}{2}=\frac{\overline {QP}\cdot\overline {PV}\cdot\sin(\alpha)}{2}$$

Since $\overline {PS}=\overline {PQ}$ and $\overline {PT}=\overline {PV}$ $$[\Delta STP]=[\Delta PVQ]$$

Now, back to the problem

[image]
Let $\overline {AB}=a$ and $\overline {IJ}=b$. Note first of all that $$\Delta BEC \cong \Delta EIF$$
See why? $\mathbf {Hint:}$

> It is obvious that $\overline {CE}=\overline {EF}$. Use the properties of right triangles in order to show that all angles are equal.

Thus $${(\overline{CE})^2}={a^2}+{b^2}=S$$

Note furthermore that $$[\Delta BEC]=[\Delta EIF]=\frac{ab}{2}$$
By Lemma 1:
$$[\Delta DCG]=[\Delta BEC]=\frac{ab}{2}=[\Delta EIF]=[\Delta GFK]$$
The area of the polygon AJKGD is thus
$$[AJKGD]=[ABCD]+[CEFG]+[FIJK]+4[\Delta DCG]=2\Bigl({a^2}+{b^2}\Bigr)+2ab$$

The area of the trapezoid AJKD is moreover
$$[AJKD]=\frac{(a+b)(2a+2b)}{2}={a^2}+2ab+{b^2}$$

Finally
$$T=[\Delta DKG]=[AJKGD]-[AJKD]={a^2}+{b^2}=S \Rightarrow S=T$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86179/discussion-on-answer-by-dr-mathva-japanese-temple-problem-from-1844).

Answer (score 37):

[image]

$$|\square P_1 P_2 P_3 P_4| = (a+b)^2 = \frac12(a+b)(2a+2b) = |\square Q_1 Q_2 Q_3 Q_4|\quad=:R$$

> $$S \;=\; R - 4\cdot\frac12ab \;=\; T$$

(This space intentionally left blank.)

Comment: I wonder what tools you use to create awesome graphs like this

Comment: @Larry: I use [GeoGebra](http://geogebra.org).

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: @Blue Hey what is $a$ and what is $b$ here? Secondly what do you mean by this notation $\square$? Do you mean a square, if so $Q_{1}Q_{2}Q_{3}Q_{4}$ doesn't resemble a square :(

Comment: @crskhr: $a$ and $b$ are the lengths labeled at the bottom of the figure; they match the sides of the bottom squares. And "$\square$" in this context means merely "quadrilateral" of any shape, despite the symbol itself being more structured; compare this to "$\triangle$" (in, say, "$\triangle ABC$"), which means "triangle" of any shape, despite the symbol itself resembling an equilateral figure. (See, for instance, Wikipedia's entry for [mathematical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject#Elementary_geometry).)

Comment: @Blue Thanks a lot for clarifying :)

Answer (score 19):

Because there are so many squares, coordinates are easy to compute.

[image]

The area of the shaded square is clearly $u^2+v^2$.

The area of the shaded triangle is one-half of the absolute value of the determinant of the array

$$\left[ \begin{array}{c}
      1 &    1 &   1 \\
   2u-v &   3u &  2u \\
   3u+v & u+3v & u+v
\end{array} \right]$$

which is also $u^2+v^2$.

### I have a second solution.

[image]

$\triangle GPN$ is obtained by rotating $\triangle GSD \ 90^\circ$ clockwise.
$\triangle GQM$ is obtained by rotating $\triangle GRK \ 90^\circ$ counterclockwise.

Answer (score 13):

While the other solutions are obviously correct, they are also unnecessarily complicated.
Since the angle of the squares is not specified, <s>it must be true for all angles, so</s>* why not pick one which is simple to work with and results in a degenerate case.

[image]

*) The assumption of truth is not required since we first do show that S=T is, in fact, true (in one simple case) and skirt the rules from there on by leaving the extrapolation to the reader.
While this approach is best suited for puzzles, looking at the edge cases first is a quick way to disprove things by example, or at least check that your calculations are correct

Comment: That's a beautiful drawing, but I'm not sure if "Since the angle of the squares is not specified, it must be true for all angles" is logically sound here. It seems to be assuming the truth of the answer.

Comment: Tongue in cheek: Isn't this almost equivalent to "P is true because the question asks me to prove it"?

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled why an off-topic aside ("testing degenerate cases is useful" and "regularly check your tire pressure" are equally relevant remarks to the posed problem) with a drawing and nothing else gets so many upvotes.

"To disprove by example" is useless here, as we already know it's true; that's the puzzle: show it. This differs from the other proofs NOT by removing unneccessary complications but by removing the PROOF part; without a hint of a path to a proof, or any insight? Very weird.

Comment: If the absurdity of this isn't clear enough: Continue the logic and let the surface of the yellow square go to zero. Now both triangles are equal sized (as both are zero). So then drawing a seagreen square on its own is someway somehow corroboration that the original question is true, and the "extrapolation" of the method of proof is left to the reader?! Neat. I don't know why I ever worked for math.

Comment: The value of this view is in showing that, **if** there is a constant difference between the areas of the triangle and square, **then** that difference is zero. (Or, if there's a constant ratio, then the ratio is one; etc.) So, had the task been to *find* that constant difference (or ratio, or whatever), then consulting a particularly-convenient configuration would've made for a proper solution. In any case, this serves as a sanity check on the problem.

Answer (score 13):

The four triangles adjacent to $S$ (two of them right, two of them obtuse) all have the same area.  (Each has the same base and height as the one on the opposite side of the square, while the two right triangles are congruent.). Now rotate each of the obtuse triangles by $90^\circ$ so that they are adjacent to $T$, as shown.

[image]

What now needs to be proved is that the two shaded pentagons have equal area.  This can be done by observing that each pentagon decomposes into an isosceles right triangle and a trapezoid.  The isosceles right triangles are congruent; the trapezoids have equal area as their two bases are the same and their heights are the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long comment.

The shapes $S,\,T$ share a vertex $A$ where six angles meet, three of them right angles. The other three angles therefore sum to a right angle. Let $\theta$ be the angle in $T$, so the two other acute angles, and the right angle between them from $S$, sum to $\pi-\theta$. Since $\sin\theta=\sin(\pi-\theta)$, $T$ has the same area as $\triangle ABC$, where $BA,\,AC$ are sides of the upper squares.

The challenge, then, is to show $S$ has that much area too. Let $D$ denote the vertex of $S$ opposite $A$. I suspect we can show the quadrilateral $BACD$ has twice the area of $S$, and also twice the area of $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: I don't think that $BACD$ has twice the area of $ABC$. If you try to move $ABC$ by shearing to get a triangle with side $BC$ and something on the bottom line, the third point isn't $D$.

Comment: $BACD$ is a rhombus because its opposite sides are parallel. So it does have twice the area of $ABC$.

Comment: $BACD$ is not a rhombus.

Comment: Sorry, I meant parallellogram @D.Thomine.

Comment: Not a parallelogram either.

Comment: Oh, and still in the spirit of avoiding trigonometry: take the upper triangle, and rotate it by $\pi/2$ around $A$. Then it is obvious that it is congruent to $ABC$ (same basis, same height).

Comment: -1 If it is a comment, why not post it as a comment?

Comment: @Servaes It's too long. "Long comment" is something people often say when their contribution has to be an "answer" because of software limitations, but is far from a complete answer.

Comment: I have converted your answer into a comment.